# mockserver not compatible with the last version of google guava

Tags: java, guava

Currently I use mockServer to mock all the external services in Java. When I start mockServer :

```
mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
proxy = StartClientAndProxy(1090);
```

I receive

> NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newConcurrentHashSet().

After a bit of research, I think error occur because of the last version of the google guava-libraries and more precisely the function `com.google.common.collect.Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()` which does not exist anymore is the last version of guava.

Unfortunately, I have another lib which require the last version of guava.

What would you recommend to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that [`Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#line.255) pretty much still exists in the latest snapshot version of Guava. It was added in Release 15. MockServer [requires Guava 18](https://github.com/jamesdbloom/mockserver/blob/master/pom.xml).

My guess is that you have an older version of Guava on the classpath from *another* dependency. Find which one and adapt it.